# Function to remove all classes on images inserted into posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When posting in Wordpress, I would like to have no classes assigned to my images by default. Every time I add images into my post, I get image classes I dont need, thus having to remove them every time.

Here is an example:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5129"
```

I would like to change to:

```
<img class=""
```

I don't want to change this in the media.php, so I've read about adding a filter through the functions.php

Can someone explain how to do this for a beginner? I have no clue about php

I am using the latest Wordpress version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one liner should do it:

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', '__return_empty_string' );
```

You can read more about this filter in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_image_tag_class).
You could also use `jQuery` to achieve your goal. Another one liner

```
$('img').removeClass();
```

although I'd go with the filter one.